# Line break or something after footer in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html, line-breaks

i have a site: www.onreg.dk. As you can see, there is a footer div, but some kind of line break comes after it in IE 7/8 Quirks mode. I have no idea why, but i know this:

- If i open developer tools (F12), and remove any css attribute from any element, it works??
- If it put display:inline on the container it works, but it creates other errors.

Does anybody have any idea about whats going on? :s
If im not clear enough about the problem, let me know.

Comment: I see 350px black footer that stretches all the way to the bottom of the page... no gap or breaks. Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: try reseting margins of html, body and any other element inside footer that could me overflowing the footer with it's margin.

Comment: this might seem a silly question, but why are you looking at the site in quirks mode? You have a doctype so a user is going to have to manually switch the viewing mode through dev tools.

Comment: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=546ahc&s=7

Comment: For some strange reason, when I open the website in IE8, it opens up in quirks mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your site has a valid doctype declaration so you shouldn't need to worry about quirks mode.
As long you provide a valid doctype for all your pages the browsers will render using standards mode.

More about Browser modes [here](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/)

Comment: For some strange reason, when I open the website in IE8, it opens up in quirks mode. OP might try using the full DTD like `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">`.

Comment: @Salman A: You're exactly right. Using the full doctype as in your comment will fix it.